# How to setup authorization Header / Reset existing Header?

Tags: api, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I am working on the api test with Rest-Assured, and my scenarios are 
1.Upload 
2.GetContent

I tried adding

```
RestAssured.given().auth().basic(userName, password)
```

It doesnt authenticate me and set the header, am getting unauthenticated error.

I also tried adding

```
RestAssured.given().header("authorization", ConfigHelper.getString(user));
```

Getting the same error. The only thing that worked for me is ,

```
getRequest().header("authorization", ConfigHelper.getString(user));
```

But the problem that I have using getRequest is that am unable to reset the request with scenario 1 and 2, so if I have set authorization in scenario1 and when I try to authenticate in Scenario 2 its duplicating the authentication in Header and giving me a

> Bad Request

error. Is there a way I could reset the header?

Comment: Did you try given().auth().preemptive().basic("username", "password") ?

Comment: Yes @WilfredClement, It doesnt work either. I get unauthenticated 401 error

Comment: That's surprising, to re-assured - Are you sure you tried the .preemptive() ?

Comment: Yup, I used ,RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("userName,password) it didnt help, so I added this.setRequest( RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("userName,password)), it worked but now the problem is in the upload, i m setting content-type to multipart form-data, its not picking it up I tried adding `this,setRequest(RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("userName,password).contentType("multipart/form-data)` but am  getting **no multipart boundary param in Content-Type**

Comment: @WilfredClement resolved that issue mentioned above, I was missing to pass the boundary param, it works now. Thanks

Comment: Please post it as an answer and mark it accepted so anybody else who faces this issue can look at this for reference

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setRequest(RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic(userName, password)
                .header("Content-type", "multipart/form-data")
                .multiPart("file", new File(pathToFile, "application/json"));
```

Comment: A short explanation/comments of your code would be great.